# Running 2 infinite loops simultaneously switching control - Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am building an image processing application that reads the current screen and does some processing. The code skeleton is as given below:

```
import my_img_proc as mip
import my_app_proc as map
import time

class myprocess:
    def perform_image_processing(self,image_name):
        while True:
            mip.perform_some_image_processing_from_screen(image_name)
            time.sleep(180) # Switch to perform_another_processing as next iteration is not needed for next 3 minutes. If this processing takes more than 3 minutes, complete current iteration and then switch to the other function.

    def perform_another_processing(self,inp):
        while True:
            map.perform_some_other_image_processing_from_screen(inp)
            time.sleep(180) # Switch to perform_image_processing as next iteration is not needed for next 3 minutes. If this processing takes more than 3 minutes, pause it and switch to the other function.


mp = myprocess()
mp.perform_image_processing(my_image) # Calling of image processing to identify items from the screen capture
mp.perform_another_processing(2) # Calling of application processing to calculate values based on screen capture
```

As of now, i am able to run only one of the function at a time.

Question here is:

1. How can i run both of them simultaneously (as 2 separate thread/process??) assuming both the functions may need to access/switch the same screen at the same time.
2. One option that i think of is both functions setting a common variable (to 1/0) and passing control of execution to each other before going on to sleep? Is it possible? How do i implement it?

Any help with this regards will help me adding multiple other similar functionalities in my application.

Thanks

Bishnu

Note:

For all who could not visualize what i wanted to achieve, here is my code that works fine. This bot code will check the screens to shield(to protect from attacks) or gather (resources in the kingdom)

```
        def shield_and_gather_loop(self):
        current_shield_sts = self.renew_shield()
        num_of_gatherers = self.num_of_troops_gathering()
        gather_sleep = False if num_of_gatherers < self.Max_Army_Size else True
        shield_sleep = True if current_shield_sts == 'SHIELDED' else False
        shield_timeout= time.time() + 60 * 3 if shield_sleep == True else None
        while True:
            while shield_sleep == False: #and current_shield_sts != 'SHIELDED':
                self.reach_home_screen_from_anywhere()
                current_shield_sts = self.renew_shield()
                print("Current Shield Status @ ", datetime.datetime.now(), " :", current_shield_sts)
                shield_sleep = True
            #self.go_to_sleep("Shield Check ", hours=0, minutes=3, seconds=0)
                shield_timeout = time.time() + 60 * 3  #3 minutes from now
            while num_of_gatherers < self.Max_Army_Size and gather_sleep == False:
                if time.time() < shield_timeout:
                    self.device.remove_processed_files()
                    self.reach_kd_screen_from_anywhere()
                    self.found_rss_tile = 0
                    self.find_rss_tile_for_gather(random.choice(self.gather_items))
                    num_of_gatherers = self.num_of_troops_gathering()
                    print("Currently gathering: ", str(num_of_gatherers))
            if gather_sleep == True and shield_sleep == True:
                print("Both gather and shield are working fine.Going to sleep for 2 minutes...")
                time.sleep(120)
                # Wake up from sleep and recheck shield and gather status
                current_shield_sts = self.renew_shield()
                num_of_gatherers = self.num_of_troops_gathering()
                gather_sleep = False if num_of_gatherers < self.Max_Army_Size else True
                shield_sleep = True if current_shield_sts == 'SHIELDED' else False
```

Comment: If only one function or the other should be running at any given time, why not just call both functions from within the same thread/loop?  Threads don't buy you anything unless you are actually able to parallelize the work, which doesn't sound like the case here.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner : both the function should be running but only one should be active. Eg: when the 1st one runs, can i put the other one on pause instead of sleep?

Comment: Are you saying that if function B is midway through its calculations, function A should pause function B, execute function A’s calculations, then resume function B?

Comment: Yes @JeremyFriesner . I want to utilise the sleep duration instead to switch from function A to function B and the same for function B. Is it doeable?

Comment: Or may be 2 worker threads performing 2 separate action and a manager thread controlling which thread would be active currently based on some global variable??

Comment: Please try to improve your question. What are you actually trying to do? Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell : I am trying to build a gaming bot that alternates between gather and shield. Gather has low priority than shield. Gather can take lot of time to complete. I have added my code to the question for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the obvious thing to do is this, as it satisfies your criteria of having only one of the two actions running at a time:

```
import my_img_proc as mip
import my_app_proc as map
import time

class myprocess:
    def perform_image_processing(self,image_name,inp):
        while True:
            mip.perform_some_image_processing_from_screen(image_name)
            map.perform_some_other_image_processing_from_screen(inp)
            time.sleep(180)

mp = myprocess()
mp.perform_image_processing(my_image,2)
```

If you need something more elaborate (such as `perform_some_other_image_processing_from_screen()` being able to interrupt a call to `perform_some_image_processing_from_screen()` before it has returned), that might require threads, but it would also require your `perform_*()` functions to serialize access to the data they are manipulating, which would make them slower and more complicated, and based on the comments supplied at the bottom of your example, it doesn't sound like the second function can do any useful work until the first function has completed its identification task anyway.

As a general principle, it's probably worthwhile to move the `while True: [...] sleep(180)` loop out of the function call and into the top-level code, so that the caller can control its behavior directly.  Calling a function that never returns doesn't leave a lot of room for customization to the caller.

```
import my_img_proc as mip
import my_app_proc as map
import time

class myprocess:
    def perform_image_processing(self,image_name,inp):
       mip.perform_some_image_processing_from_screen(image_name)  
       map.perform_some_other_image_processing_from_screen(inp)

mp = myprocess()
while True:
   mp.perform_image_processing(my_image,2)
   sleep(180)
```

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. As suggested, i modified the code to combine both the functionalities into a single function and used variables to share between the functions and control sleeping behaviour.